# If $ab>0$, show that $\dfrac{a}{b}+\dfrac{b}{a}\ge2$.

Tags: inequality, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

If $ab>0$, show that $\dfrac{a}{b}+\dfrac{b}{a}\ge2$.

I am really sorry for the basic question, but I want to make things clear for me. By the AM-GM inequality we have $$\dfrac{a}{b}+\dfrac{b}{a}\ge2\sqrt{\dfrac{a}{b}\cdot\dfrac{b}{a}}=2$$ Is this enough? I mean we know that the inequality holds only for positive numbers $a$ and $b$, but here we can have $a<0$ and $b<0$ and then $ab>0$ will also hold.

Comment: $a/b$ and $b/a$ are both positive as either both $a$ and $b$ are positive or both are negative. So what you have done works.

Comment: Or, without breaking it down by cases, you can use AM-GM for $\,\frac{a^2}{ab}+\frac{b^2}{ab}\,$.

Comment: @MathLover, thank you, I think my solution works just fine. Why are the others talking about breaking it down by cases? $\dfrac{a}{b}$ and $\dfrac{b}{a}$ are always positive if $ab>0$.

Comment: Of course your solution works. But you will have to acknowledge that $a, b \lt 0$ is a possibility and state that for both cases, $a/b$ and $b/a$ are positive hence applying AM-GM... In other words, someone looking at your solution should also see your reasoning.

Comment: Personally, I just added another way to solve the problem to give an alternative method. It is thanks to seeing other solutions that you get creative and how you really grow as a mathematician.

Comment: If $ab> 0$ then $a/b+b/a-2\ge  0\iff ab(a/b+b/a-2)\ge 0\iff a^2+b^2-2ab\ge 0\iff (a-b)^2\ge 0.$

Answer (score 1):

The proof below works pretty well.
\begin{align}
&(b-a)^2\geq 0\\
\iff &a^2+b^2-2ab\geq 0\\
\iff &a^2+b^2\geq 2ab\\
\implies&\frac{a}{b}+\frac{b}{a}\geq 2.
\end{align}
In the last step I divided by $ab$. It works because $ab$ is positive.

Answer (score 0):

You've almost had a perfect solution, but just by adding few cases, you can make it perfect.

\begin{align}
&\text{Case 1. } a>0, b>0. \\
&\Rightarrow \frac a b + \frac b a \geq 2 \sqrt{\frac a b \cdot \frac b a} = 2\text{ (AM-GM).} \\
\ \\
&\text{Case 2. } a<0, b<0. \\
&\text{let } a^*=-a, b^*=-b. \Rightarrow a^*>0, b^*>0.\\
&\Rightarrow \frac a b + \frac b a=\frac {a^*} {b^*} + \frac {b^*} {a^*} \geq 2 \sqrt{\frac {a^*}{b^*} \cdot \dfrac {b^*}{a^*}}=2 \text{ (AM-GM)}.
\end{align}

Comment: There’s no reason to introduce $a^*$ and $b^*$, since we already have $a/b,b/a>0$ in both cases.

Comment: In either case, the two numbers $\frac ab$ and $\frac ba$ are positive, and those are the ones we are using AM-GM on. I see no need for cases even if you are trying to be perfectly rigorous.

Answer (score 0):

I have followed another reasoning to prove the statement.

Case 1: $a=b$
$$\frac{a}{a}+\frac{a}{a}=2\quad \blacksquare$$

Case 2: $a\neq b$

Notice that $ab>0$ is the same as saying $a,b\neq 0$, and both have the same sign (which later becomes irrelevant).

$$\frac{a}{b}+\frac{b}{a}=\frac{a^2+b^2}{ab}=\frac{a^2+2ab+b^2-2ab}{ab}=\frac{(a+b)^2}{ab}-2\geq2$$
$$\frac{(a+b)^2}{ab}\geq4;\quad (a+b)^2\geq 4ab;\quad a^2+2ab+b^2\geq4ab;\quad a^2-2ab+b^2=(a-b)^2\geq0$$

which we know it is true regardless of the signs of $a$, $b$ since a squared number is always positive $\blacksquare$

Comment: I was about to put a similar answer to this, but i simplified the function from $a^2 +  b^2 \ge 2ab \to a^2 - 2ab + b^2 \ge 0 \to (a - b)^2 \ge 0$. I could not continue from there though...

Comment: In your case, you already know that they will be equal to 0 when $a=b$ and greater than 0 since any squared number is positive. I decided to go the long way round to show it with a sum instead of a difference.

Comment: You should have $\frac{(a+b)^2}{ab} -2\geq 2$... also I don't know why you need the separate case fir $a=b$

Comment: Oops yes, thanks for spotting the typo! I separated the case initially because I thought it would influence the result, but then you realize quite fast it is irrelevant and you can just go with the other case.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to make any cases at all. We have $ab > 0$ (this is given), $a^2 > 0$ and $b^2 > 0$. Just apply the AM-GM inequality to $\frac{a^2}{ab}$ and $\frac{b^2}{ab}$, which we know are positive numbers.

$$\frac a b + \frac b a = \frac{a^2}{ab} + \frac{b^2}{ab} \ge 2 \sqrt{\frac{a^2b^2}{a^2b^2}} = 2$$

Answer (score 0):

I would be even simpler. $ab>0$, OK.

But really $(a-b)^2=a^2+b^2-2ab=(a+b)^2-4ab>0$

Thus $\frac{(a+b)^2}{ab}-2>2$

That is $\frac{a^2+b^2}{ab}>2$

Or $\frac{a}{b}+\frac{b}{a}>2$

Answer (score 0):

If $ab>0$ then $a/b>0$ as well.  So
$$\frac{a}{b}+\frac{b}{a}-2=
\left(\sqrt{\frac{a}{b}}-\sqrt{\frac{b}{a}}\right)^2.$$